# Grid Has Gaps if Odd Pixel Width/Height

Tags: html, css

This is driving me mad but I'm happy that I was able to replicate the problem.

Here's the goal - I'm using grid to show a clear middle with slightly transparent edge elements.

Here's the problem - there's a slight gap that shows up between the different sections of the grid only when the width or height is an **ODD** pixel amount.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 75px; /* this seems to be the problem */
  height: 85px; /* this seems to be the problem */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  grid-template-columns: 30px 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 1fr;
}

.grid-obj {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

.clear {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj "></div>
  <div class="grid-obj clear"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
</div>
```

I know it's a short question but help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: One solution is to use `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` for the grid element. Not sure why this works but it does. It makes everything else blurry though... Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems related to how you center the grid itself. Not sure why, and I haven't tested cross-browser, but setting the grid's container to flex solves the issue.

I.e.: remove:

```
.grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

add:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 75px;
  /* this seems to be the problem */
  height: 85px;
  /* this seems to be the problem */
  grid-template-columns: 30px 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 1fr;
}

.grid-obj {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

.clear {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj "></div>
  <div class="grid-obj clear"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
  <div class="grid-obj"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works - I was originally looking for it to be absolutely positioned because there are other elements in the container than need to be positioned but I can just make those elements absolutely positioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lines are appear because you have used `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to make Grid at center of screen.

Please remove `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and `margin: -42px 0 0 -37px` to make Grid at center of the stage.